# Query Select group by last character in field

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to do a query search on a table and return a count of rows that end in the same character.  For example, Cd312a, fdhEA and 42dA would be grouped together under 'A'.  Below is an example of the table and what I would like to see returned.

Table Tbl_Table

```
ID| _Name     |
1 | S033114A  |
2 | S033114B  |
3 | S033114B  |
4 | S033114K  |
4 | S033114K  |
```

Results

```
Type  | Count
  A   |  1
  B   |  2
  K   |  2
```

My Current Code

```
SELECT RIGHT(_Name,1) as Type, Count(Type) as Count FROM Tbl_Table
```

Anyone that can shed some light on my my query isn't returning what I am expecting would be helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: You missed the GROUP BY RIGHT(_Name,1) at the end of the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Before**

```
SELECT RIGHT(_Name,1) as Type, Count(Type) as Count
FROM Tbl_Table
```

**After**

```
SELECT RIGHT(_Name,1) as Type, Count(*) as Count
FROM Tbl_Table
Group by RIGHT(_Name,1)
Order by RIGHT(_Name,1)
```

**Edit**

Removed "Type" from the Count function to address the "Unknown column 'Type' in 'field list'" problem.

Comment: I get the response : 
Unknown column 'Type' in 'field list'